# Prevented from posting question

Tags: bug, ios-app

I attempted to post a bug report but it failed because I was missing one of the required tags. After adding the tag, I couldn't post the question because I had triggered the timer to prevent posting too frequently, even though my post hadn't been submitted.

[image: 1 minute wait]

Update: now I have to wait 20 minutes to post my second bug report? Let's see if I remember to come back and click submit in 20 minutes...

[image: 20 minute wait]

Comment: Ouch, unless you are on a throttled IP address, that seems overly harsh a restriction for a new user posting their first question. Are you logged in to the same network now as your attempt to post the question?

Comment: Yes I am9012345

Comment: Would sound like you're on a throttled IP..